# How to get list of tasks assigned to me in an Asana project

Tags: api, task, project, workspace, asana

How can i get a list of tasks assigned to me in an **Asana** project
I tried

```
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/projectId/tasks?assignee=me
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?project=projectId&assignee=me
```

but it returns even those tasks as well which are not assigned to me.
So is it possible in **Asana** to get tasks assigned to me in a project?

Answer (score 0):

When you target projects API you can't (as I know) get tasks that are assigned to you.

Workaround would be to target tasks that are assigned to you with project ID in it and then separate (or isolate) them by project in your app.

Example tasks call:

```
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?opt_fields=assignee,name,projects&assignee=me&limit=10&workspace=your_workspace_number
```

Where `your_workspace_number` is of course your number.

Try it in explorer here https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks

Comment: but i want tasks assigned to me in a project **not in a workspace**

Comment: I understand your question and this is workaround like I said in answer. Because, as I know, it is not possible to target projects and get tasks in it that are assigned to specific person. You can target tasks and set it to send project id, like in answer, and then play with it. You just need to group tasks that are in specific project and thats it.